# "Standard" openings for appliances between kitchen cabinets?

Tags: kitchens, appliances

Are there any building standards for sizes of appliance openings between kitchen cabinets?

I am planning to remodel my kitchen and wonder how much openings should I leave for my range and fridge. Currently, it is a very tight fit for my 30" range, but quite generous 38" opening for my 35 3/4" fridge (which actually does not require that much). How much tighter should I go?

So far, most advice that I found says "Check the appliance's owner's manual", and this sure makes sense, however, I don't want to build my kitchen around particular appliance models. I want it to be able to last for decades without me being forced to bear the consequences of my poor decisions.

Comment: No tighter on the 38"...

Comment: Leave bigger openings so you can fit larger appliances when the decision is made (or for future upgrades), then use trim panels screwed in to fill the gap if you don't like the gaps showing. At a minimum, the trim panels will hide the dust that'll collect. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Appliances come in different sizes. Stoves

- 24", (Apartment)
- 30", (Normal)
- 36" (Ohhh, look at my stove, it's a status symbol)

are common here - presumably more metric countries have metric common sizes, though sometimes they have odd metric common sizes that are really inch sizes.

Refrigerators span an even wider range these days with the "French Door extra-wide models" on the high width end. Their height also varies. [Maytag](https://www.maytag.com/blog/kitchen/guide-to-refrigerator-sizes-dimensions.html) says `Standard refrigerator sizes range from around 24 to 40 inches in width, 62 to 72 inches in height and 29 to 36 inches in depth.`

If you want options for future replacements, leave more space. Then figure out how to use it if the present appliance doesn't fill it all. Having to shoehorn into a particular-sized hole limits your purchase options quite severely. So, putting an appliance at the end of a counter run (rather than boxing it in)is more flexible, when possible/practical.

Comment: Thank you. "If you want options for future replacements, leave more space" - I am struggling to think "how much more"? So, is my existing 38" opening a product of some building standard that would be unwise for me to change?

Comment: Depends if you want to accommodate the french-door types in ever wider width, or not. Or limit your future options to 35, 32, 29 etc. inches. I suspect your 38" was intended to take 36" (a formerly common top width for a fridge before the double-door craze) with 1" clearance. Since then the fridge makers have gone bigger (or wider/shallower.) At present you can still find plenty that will fit your space.

Comment: You've described _nominal_ sizes. That doesn't really address cabinetry opening dimensions.

Comment: How is a 36" stove a status symbol? Mine is 48", my sister-in-laws is 60".

Comment: It's a symbol of how _little_ you care about status, @GlenYates. ;)

Comment: My stove measures 61”. How much tolerance do I want to leave between the cabinets? 1/8” on either side?

Answer (score 1):

The "rule of thumb" is 30" for a range and upper cabinet mounted Micro, or range hood.
24' for a dishwasher. 36x 72 inch min. for a standard refrigerator. The refrigerators can be tricky. Often the newer counter depth friges need specific space for the door to be able to swing if next to a wall.

Comment: But is it "36" sharp" or "36 1/2"" or something like that for a nominal 36" appliance?

Comment: Most appliances in the standard sizes are themselves slightly smaller than the 24. 30, 36 inch size so they fit into the standard size opening. No need to make your openings larger than the standard size for standard appliances.